# Model-wide validation for a Field type in Django ie., validate that all DecimalField of a model is greater than 0

Tags: django, django-validation

I have three Decimal fields that all have the same validator:

`

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    one = models.DecimalField(validators=[great_than_zero])
    two = models.DecimalField(validators=[great_than_zero]
    three = models.DecimalField(validators=[great_than_zero]
```

`

Is there a pythonic way to enforce this validator for the entire model, so that no Decimal Field can have a negative number. If I know that all of my Decimal fields will be positive, it would be nice to not right the same piece of code for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a field yourself with:

```
# app_name/fields.py

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db.models import DecimalField


def greater_than_zero(value):
    if value <= 0:
        raise ValidationError('The value should be greater than zero.', code='min_value_eq')


class PositiveDecimalField(DecimalField):
    default_validators = [greater_than_zero]
```

and then use that field in your models:

```
# app_name/models.py

from app_name.fields import PositiveDecimalField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    one = PositiveDecimalField()
    two = PositiveDecimalField()
    three = PositiveDecimalField()
```